# Zend: What is the most common way to create Rest Zend routes?

Tags: zend-framework, rest, routes, nested-routes

I'm using default Zend_Rest_Route to generate Rest routes:

So given I just put `resources.router.routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route` inside application.ini and now have Rest Routes for users

```
GET users
POST users
GET users/:id        
GET users/:id/edit   
PUT users/:id
DELETE users/:id
```

But how about nested resources? Given I need

```
users/:user_id/articles
users/:user_id/articles/:id
... etc
```

Is there any way to keep routes REST'y?
Will appreciate any example of creating such nested routes

P.S. I'm using ZF version 1.10.8

Regards, M

Comment: Hy, have you resolved? I have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be late here, but i want to answer your question.

As mentioned **[here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Rest-Route-and-application-ini-td1014158.html)**, the creation of rest route configuration in application.ini may not work.

Coming to your point of the route configurations, you can use **Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex** for defining routes and corresponding mappings. Refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152502/matching-multiple-urls-with-parameters-using-zend-controller-router-route-regex-i)** question of myne. Might help you.